# Entity foreign key relationship

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I'm fairly new to MVC and am having difficulties creating a relationship between two entities.

Hotels entity (a view):

```
[Table("hotels", Schema = "dbo")]
public class Hotel
{
    [Key]
    [Display(Name= "Hotel Code")]
    public String code { get; set; }
    .
    .
    .
    [InverseProperty("Hotel")]
    public virtual ICollection<Charge> Charges { get; set; }
```

Charges entity:

```
[Table("charges", Schema = "dbo")]
public class Charge
{
    [Key]
    public Int32 id { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Hotel Code")]
    public String hotelCode { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Criteria")]
    public Int32 criteriaID { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Classification")]
    public Int32 chargeClassificationID { get; set; }
.
.
.
    [ForeignKey("hotelCode")]
    public virtual Hotel Hotel { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("criteriaID")]
    public virtual ICollection<CalculatedDebit> CalculatedDebits { get; set; }
```

CalculatedDebit Entity (calculatedDebits is a view if it matters):

```
[Table("calculatedDebits_distinct", Schema = "dbo")]
public class CalculatedDebit
{
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 0)]
    public Int32 criteriaID { get; set; }

    [Column(Order = 1)]
    public Int32 classificationID { get; set; }

    [Column(Order = 2)]
    public string hotelCode { get; set; }
}
```

When I call this:

```
Hotel hotel = db.Hotels.Find(id);
```

I get the query below:

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT 
[Extent1].[criteriaID] AS [criteriaID], 
[Extent1].[classificationID] AS [classificationID],
[Extent1].[hotelCode] AS [hotelCode]
FROM [dbo].[calculatedDebits_distinct] AS [Extent1]
WHERE [Extent1].[criteriaID] = @EntityKeyValue1',N'@EntityKeyValue1 int',@EntityKeyValue1=6709
```

Instead of the criteria value to query off of, I am getting the charge value.  My preference would be to have the WHERE clause use all three values from calculatedDebits (which will mean the collection is not required)...but if that is not possible, I am OK with getting the record I want/need after the fact.

Any help with what I am missing is appreciative.  I have also tried adding a Charges collection to CalculatedDebits with InverseProperty, but I get this error:

> > The InversePropertyAttribute on property 'Charges' on type 'TheProgram.Models.CalculatedDebit' is not valid. The property 'CalculatedDebit' is not a valid navigation property on the related type 'TheProgram.Models.Charge'. Ensure that the property exists and is a valid reference or collection navigation property.

Comment: "When I execute the code" - what is "the code"? And what exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Updated original posting.  I'm trying to get data from Calculated Debits based on values from Charges.  A view using Charges will display something depending on whether CalculatedDebits for that Charge is empty.

Comment: I'm guessing you mean `CalculatedDebit calculatedDebit = db.CalculatedDebits.Find(id);` instead of `Hotel hotel = db.Hotels.Find(id);`, right? The SQL query has nothing to do with hotels. I don't understand your paragraph below the SQL query. You are apparently passing `6709` as `id` into `Find`. That generates a query by the key which is `criteriaID`. So, this query is expected. What is exactly the problem?

Comment: Sorry, query was there before I added the hotel part.  Basically I call db.Hotels.Find where id is the hotel code.  From Hotels, I get the list of charges for that hotel.  Then within Charges I want the calculated debits.  But instead of filtering by Criteria ID, it is using the Charge ID.